# I am trying to pass in a DISABLED checkbox value to the controller, but it does not seem to be passed

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, checkbox

Below is the code to select all the server

```
<input type="checkbox" id="all_maintenace" class="checkbox " style="vertical-align: middle;"
 name="all_chkb_maintenace" value=""> Maintenace All </th>
```

Below is the code to select individually

```
<input type="checkbox" id="maintenace_{{ $value->id }}" class="checkbox checkbox_maintenace"
 style="vertical-align: middle;" name="chkb_maintenace[]" value="{{ $value->id }}"
 {{ ($value->websiteStatus==0)?"checked":'' }}>
<input type="text" name="chkb_all_users[]" value="{{ $value->id }}" hidden>
```

Below will be the code to disable / freeze the maintenance checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" id="freeze_{{ $value->id }}" class="checkbox checkbox_freeze"
 style="vertical-align: middle;" name="frz_maintenace[]" value="{{ $value->id }}">
<input type="text" name="chkb_all_users_frz[]" value="{{ $value->id }}" hidden>
```

Below will be the script

```
$(document).on('click', '#all_maintenace', function() {
          var checkboxes = $('.checkbox_maintenace');
          var chk_value = $('.checkbox_maintenace').val();


          $.each(checkboxes, function(i, v) {
            var disabled = $(v).prop("disabled");
            var checked_length = $(v).is(":checked");

            $(v).prop("checked", $('#all_maintenace').prop("checked"));

            if (disabled && !checked_length) {
              $(v).prop('checked', false); // Unchecks it
            } else if (disabled && checked_length) {
              $(v).prop('checked', true); // Checks it
            }

          });
        });
    $(function() {
          $(".checkbox_freeze").on("change", function() {
            var ticked = $(this).val();
            const checked = this.checked;
            $("#maintenace_"+ticked).attr("disabled", checked)
          });
        });
```

controller:

```
$all_user = $request->chkb_all_users;
$selected_user = $request->has('chkb_maintenace') ? $request->chkb_maintenace : [];
$un_selected_user = array_diff($all_user, $selected_user);
```

So my question is how do I pass to the controller the checkbox value that I have disabled/frozen, while the other checkboxes that I have not disabled/frozen are passed into the controller

Comment: A disabled input wil not be posted.  You can re-enable it before you post, or lock it using js

Comment: @GertB. and how do i lock it using js.
if i am re-enabling it on the script, then the blade view will be enabled as well right, and i dont want that, i want the view to stay disabled while the value of the checkbox is passed onto the controller.

Comment: Well you can add a class and prevent changes using js. `$('.locked').on('change click',function (e){
   e.preventDefault();
})` When you enable it on submit, it will be enabled for a very short time on the page, indeed. Most of the time that does not really matter that much. But I understand that is not a good option in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple.Do like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="freeze_{{ $value->id }}" class="checkbox checkbox_freeze"
 style="vertical-align: middle;" name="frz_maintenace[]" value="{{ $value->id }}">
<input type="text" name="chkb_all_users_frz[]" value="{{ $value->id }}" hidden>
<input type="hidden" id="checkbox_status" value="0" />
```

your js should like this

```
$(function() {
 $(".checkbox_freeze").on("change", function() {
    var ticked = $(this).val();
    const checked = this.checked;
    if(checked){
     $('#checkbox_status').val(1);
    } else {
     $('#checkbox_status').val(0);
    }
    $("#maintenace_"+ticked).attr("disabled", checked)
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use simple machanism to solve it. use hidden text field and when you checked your checkbox you can assign value as a '1'. when you freeze it you can assign it as a '0'. very simple

```
<input type="hidden" id="checkbox_status" value="0" />
```

js side you can change that value when you click checkbox

```
$('#checkbox_status').val(1);
```

Comment: sorry, i dont really understand, but where should i put the hidden text field at? and where should i put the js? Am beginner to this thanks for helping

Comment: you can use that hidden text field with your checkbox. then you can catch checked status and you can update above text field. after that you can send that hidden text field to your controller

Comment: i still could not solve it, i might think that i am doing something wrong but i am not sure.